# Fix JS code: Append multiple values out of checkboxes to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I found this code that replaced the link text (= "Show") by the checked checkbox values. Now, I am looking for a code that appends/removes the checked/unchecked values to the link url itself.

```js
function calculate() {
  var arr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e, i) {
    return +e.value;
  });
  $("[href$='feature=']").text('the checked values are: ' + arr.join(','));
}

calculate();
$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Teamsport" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Individual sport" />
</div>

<div><a href="/best/?price=123&amp;feature=">Show</a></div>

<a href="/best/?price=123&amp;feature=Teamsport">Show</a>
```

Thank you very much for your help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop instead of [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)...

Also, since you wish to change the `href`... And that it is used with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), I would save the element in a variable before the `href` changes. And the same for the `href` "base" value itself. Because on second click, the `href` will not end in `feature=`.

So here is a working demo:

```js
function calculate() {
  var arr = [];
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i,v) {
    arr.push(v.value);
  });
  
  // The array in console
  console.log(arr);
  
  // Join it has a string
  var arr_string = arr.join(",");  

  // Use the string in the link's text AND the href
  link
    .text('the checked values are: ' + arr_string)
    .attr('href', link_href_base + arr_string);
  
  // The link's href in console
  console.log(link.attr("href"));
}

// Variables that won't change
var link = $("[href$='feature=']");
var link_href_base = link.attr("href");

calculate();
$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Teamsport" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Individual sport" />
</div>

<div><a href="/best/?price=123&amp;feature=">Show</a></div>
```

Comment: Why each instead of map? Isn't that a perfect example for map or is it just personal preference?

Comment: I would use map to filter some elements that does not meet a condition. I your case, you know that all the elements are checked because you used the `:checked` selector. ;)

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't what map is for, to filter an array there is `Array​.filter` or in jQuery `jQuery.grep`, map is supposed to transform **each** element to a new one (to map them). @louys-patrice-bessette

Comment: Yes... I double checked and you're right. But `$('input:checkbox:checked')`is not an array, but a jQuery collection of elements...